# DirectX SDK project - porting to VS2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sdk, directx

I'm porting to visual studio 2012 a solution with a project which uses some headers from the directX SDK in this path:

```
C:/../Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Samples/C++/DXUT11/Core
```

the problem is: I'm encountering all the (in)famous re-definitions warnings:

```
14>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h(12): warning C4005: 'DXGI_STATUS_OCCLUDED' : macro redefinition
14>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\winerror.h(49449) : see previous definition of 'DXGI_STATUS_OCCLUDED'
```

and the only solution I found is to eliminate the SDK path (which is C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include) from my project. Unfortunately I can't do it this time because I need the DXUT11

Any advice on how to completely port to VS2012 such a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions you need are [buried in MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the crucial part of which is copied below for posterity.

[image: MSDN]