# DirectX D3DXVec3Normalize unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, directx

I have simple DirectX project:

```
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <d3dx10math.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d10.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")

int main()
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 u(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 v(2.0f, 1.0f, 3.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 a, b, c, d, e;

    float l = D3DXVec3Length(&u);
    float s = D3DXVec3Dot(&u, &v);

    D3DXVec3Normalize(&d, &u); // <- problem is here

    return 0;
 }
```

I added include and lib directories in my project properties and everything works fine, except D3DXVec3Normalize line. When I run the program it says: "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DXVec3Normalize@8 referenced in function _main".

Can anyone explain why D3DXVec3Length and D3DXVec3Dot functions work OK (without Normalize line) and D3DXVec3Normalize produces error?

P.S. I use DirectX SDK June 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker error means that basically the code is fine, but you did not provide the location of `D3DXVec3Normalize` function, the library where the actual function resides.

MSDN [suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it's D3dx9.lib, so you add to your code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "D3dx9.lib") // this can supposedly be D3dx10.lib as well
```

Comment: Also, for using legacy DirectX code with VS2012, [refer to my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16632776/2065121).

Comment: Roger's suggestion above (another answer) is equally fine. I prefer hinting through `#pragma` because it's easier to reference necessary libraries along with header inclusion - no need to fine tune through project settings at all.

Comment: Actually it's important to get the libs and headers in the correct order for VS2012 since the DX stuff was moved into the Windows 8 SDK, although in general I prefer `#pragma`'s too.

Comment: Thanks. I added DirectX 9 libraries to the project and it works now. So, d3dx9 contains this function and d3dx10, d3dx11 don't contain it? Looks really odd for me ...